# MS Access - Add Label and Text Box based on form selection

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have form Add_Mitigation. On that form, there is a field Activity_Due_Date_1.

There are regular instances where the Activity_Due_Date_1 will be updated. In doing so, we don't want to lose the previous Activity_Due_Date value(s). Therefore, I was thinking of adding a button Update_Due_Date.

On Click, it would add the Label Activity_Due_Date_2, where the number at the end of the Label is one higher than the previous Label. It would also add a Text Box for the user to enter the updated due date.

I'm not clear on how to code the addition of a new Label and Text Box. Additionally, is there a cleaner way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> There are regular instances where the Activity_Due_Date_1 will be updated. In doing so, we don't want to lose the previous Activity_Due_Date value(s)

If you need to keep a log of all Due Dates, you need to store them in a table somewhere. Adding a textbox/label control programmatically is possible, but pretty complex for what you are trying to do, fairly difficult when firing from the form you are modifying, must be run from a split front-end, and will not save the data contained therein, deleting the history when you close the form by default unless you also build a save procedure among all of those other details.

My suggestion is to look at your table structure and determine how to store a log of due dates and when they were committed. It will depend on whether you need a permanent history or only the most-recently overwritten date.

**Most Recent Date Only**: depending on your structure, adding a column to the table currently storing the date would probably be sufficient. Your form then would always have two textboxes, but if the second is null you can use the textbox's/label's "Visible" property to hide them when blank. When a date changes, the old value can be placed in the second field, overwriting the second field's value if it is not null.

**Full change history**: depending on your structure you could create a new table with a FK joining to the original table, a field to store the Due Date, and a field to store a date/timestamp of when the record was produced. Using queries you can select the most recent datestamp to find the currently committed due date. Instead of using sequenced textboxes, you could use a datasheet subform or a listbox displaying the due date history for the given record.

Comment: Going with your "Full change history" recommendation, would I add an After Update event to the Activity_Due_Date text box, adding that due date along with a date/timestamp and FK to the newly created table?

Comment: Yes, the AfterUpdate could be used to save the new date.